# UISegmentedControl : Could not call the method in ios 5.0

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios5, ios4

I am modifying one iPhone app,

when I am changing the value of segmented button,

It should call the method,

```
- (void) setSelectedSegmentIndex:(NSInteger)index
```

Which I have overridden in my custom class.

[image]

There is No IBAction associated with segments.

**In ios 4.3 it is getting called.
But, In ios 5.0 it is not called.**

Here is its **ResultUnitSwitch.h** file

```
@interface ResultUnitSwitch : UISegmentedControl {

    id <ResultUnitDelegate> delegate;

    MCUnit *activeUnit;

    NSArray *units;             
}


There is a method call stack for ios 4.3
```

[image]

So, Why it is called in ios 4.3 and not ios 5.0 of same project is it anything changed is UISegmentedControl

Answer (score 1):

`setSelectedSegmentIndex` is a property setter designed for external usage. you rely on **undocumented internal framework usage** for your app so there is no guarantee that this will work forever.

You can overwrite an init-Method (`initWithCoder:`if you use XIBs) to add a method of your subclass as event target:

```
[self addTarget:self action:@selector(action:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
```